# How to get a method's variable inside a class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to get the `result()` method's variable that is called `word`.

If someone knows how to do it, please help me.

```
def result(self,var1,word="",mainlista=mainlista):
    try:
        for i in range(int(var1)):
            x = random.choice(mainlista)
            word += x
    except IndexError:
        pass
```

Comment: The function should return it.

Comment: Why do you have `try`? Nothing in that code can raise `IndexError`.

Comment: Or the function could assign `x` to an instance variable.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please put the complete code

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want result() to return `word` you can create an instance variable for it see example below.

```py
import random


mainlista = ['london', 'paris', 'tokyo']


class WordPower:
    def __init__(self, var1, mainlista):
        self.var1 = var1
        self.mainlista = mainlista
        self.word = ''

    def result(self):
        try:
            for _ in range(self.var1):
                x = random.choice(self.mainlista)
                self.word += x
        except IndexError as e:
            print(e)


var1 = 2
a = WordPower(var1, mainlista)
a.result()
word = a.word
print(word)

# tokyoparis
```